# jquery validation remote rule not firing

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

i'm using jquery validation on my Registration form and have just added in a remote rule on the email field.  Everything except the remote rule/msg is working.  There's no call to check_email.php at all.  I've confirmed that I'm pointing to the correct .js file (not the .min.js).

Here's a snippet.  Let me know if you want the whole validate function.  I'm using the submitHandler and it's working correctly, even preventing duplicate emails from being inserted, but I obviously want remote to function properly and don't know why it's not being called.

```
   $("#frmRegisterWebuser").validate({
  rules:{
         reg_email:{
                    required: true,
                    email: true,
             remote: {
                 url: 'check_email',
                 type: 'POST',
                 data: {'email': $('#reg_email').val()}
             }
            },
         username: {
                   required: true,
                   minlength: 3
                   },
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm wondering if you are missing a file extension? or if that has anything to do with your problem... the code looks good though

Comment: If you're trying to check the file at `check_email.php`, then your `url` parameter needs to contain the path to the `check_email.php` file.  Presently, it _appears_ that it does not.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a spelling mistake in a URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change url param to `check_mail.php` or `/check_mail.php`

Comment: Or maybe `check_email.php`.

Comment: changing it to /check_mail worked.  Thanks!!

Comment: @JenBorn, perhaps explain how `/check_mail` points to `check_email.php`... notice _both_ the spelling and file extension.

Comment: sheesh!  typo--here, not in my code.  So the fix was the forward slash: /check_email  The file is check_email.php but I've mucked about in .htaccess so that I don't use extensions.  So savvy.

Comment: @Sparky please note that the typo was only here, so there was a valid fix.  thanks!

Comment: @JenBorn, I see that.  However, this answer is a guess in the other direction.  (Notice how he really thought the problem was the missing `.php`) Critical information was missing from your OP... if you had mentioned the `htaccess` rewrite and shown your file hierarchy, then anyone could have seen the missing slash as the real issue without making a random guess.